# Python asammdf library requires dependencies

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqtgraph

I am completely new to Python and try to run the example code 'Working with MDF' of a library called 'asammdf' (code can be found here: https://asammdf.readthedocs.io/en/master/examples.html)

When I run the .py-script I get the following error message:

> WARNING:root:Signal plotting requires pyqtgraph or matplotlib
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/martin/PycharmProjects/mdfp3/WorkingWithMDF.py", line 46, in 
>       mdf4_cut.get('Float64_Signal').plot()

I added the pyqtgraph and matplotlib packages using the dependency manager in PyCharm, but no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
Running the `pip install` commands for the packages results in 'Requirement already satisfied' statements (see below)

> (venv) martins-mbp-2:mdfp3 martin$ pip install pyqtgraph
>   Requirement already satisfied: pyqtgraph in ./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.10.0)
>   Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pyqtgraph) (1.17.4)

and

> (venv) martins-mbp-2:mdfp3 martin$ pip install matplotlib Requirement
>   already satisfied: matplotlib in ./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages
>   (3.1.1) Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in
>   ./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib) (0.10.0)
>   Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11 in
>   ./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.17.4)
>   Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in
>   ./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.1)
>   Requirement already satisfied:
>   pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in
>   ./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.4.5)
>   Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in
>   ./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.1.0)
>   Requirement already satisfied: six in
>   ./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib)
>   (1.13.0) Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in
>   ./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools-40.8.0-py3.7.egg (from
>   kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib) (40.8.0)

Comment: The only thing we can know is what the error tells you: You need to have matplotlib or pyqtgraph installed.

Comment: "No luck" as in "I had no luck installing them" or "I installed them but get exactly the same error"?

Comment: @FiddleStix thanks for support, but it looks like the packages are installed (please see what I added).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that you need PyQt5 as well as either pyqtgraph or matplotlib.  The GUI packages are considered 'optional', which would explain why they don't get installed automatically.  FYI, I found this out by reading the exception in the asammdf\gui\plot.py file.

The GUI dependecies can be installed using this pip command

```
pip install asammdf[gui]
```

Comment: The problem is that I expected that pyqtgraph had PyQt as dependency. I will address this in the setup file

Comment: @danielhrisca I've never bumped into a package maintainer on here.  Kudos to you for being on the ball.  Do you have an alert set up or something?

Comment: I'm a member of the Night's Watch keeping a vigilent eye out for trouble